# UITableView - (void)configureView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm working now with table views and detailed views, you know that one which appears when you select element in your table.

there is a method - (void)configureView which is called in viewDidLoad and descriptions say it updates interface.

I've got something like this:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

 if (self.detailItem) {
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.detailItem;
}
if (self.subjectItem) {
    self.subjectLabel.text = [self.subjectItem description];
}
self.imageView.image = self.imageItem;}
```

my question is: is "description" property required? because it works without it(the first item and imageView), and if so then how syntax would look like for imageView? because "description" is only for NSStrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really description is a method of NSObject: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html 
You don't need to use it in your code above, neither for NSString.
Just be sure to assign to the properties the correct objects (i.e. self.imageItem must be an istance of UIImage).